# Jflex no reconoce el símbolo de principio de linea en NetBeans

Tags: java, compilador, jflex

Estoy desarrollando un compilador básico usando [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans), [jflex](/questions/tagged/jflex) y [jcup](/questions/tagged/jcup). Tengo un archivo `.flex` donde tengo las expresiones regulares que detectan los tokens y se envian al jcup.

Las indentaciones deben ser iguales dentro de cada bloque pero cada bloque puede tener un tamaño diferente. Tal y como hace omo en python:

```
while condicion:
    if condicion2:
                sent1
                sent2
    else:
        sent3
sent4
```

La expresion regular en cuestion busca detectar el inicio de linea y luego permitir una cantidad arbitraria de espacios en blanco hasta terminar con algo que no sea un blanco, pero NetBeans arroja un error de sintaxis al usar el simbolo "^", especificado en la documentacion de Jflex como inicio de linea (https://jflex.de/manual.html).

El codigo:
.

```java
salto_linea             =   \r|\n|\r\n
espacios_blancos        =   {salto_linea}|[ \t\f]
indentacion             =   ^[ ]+[^ ]

//      DATOS
id                      =   [A-z_]+\w*
booleano                =   (\.T\.|\.F\.)
entero                  =   [\d]+
```

El error:

```
Error in file ".\src\ejemplo\jflex\lexico.flex" (line 67): 
Syntax error.
indentacion             =   ^[ ]+[^ ]
                            ^
```